What rule of semblances does Qrow's transformation breaks that it convinces Nora that Magic is real?
Like if from my knowledge of what semblances can do, I don't see any reason turning into a crow would be unusual

Conservation of matter is not obeyed as seen with Flynt's clones
Conservation of form is not obeyed as seen with Ruby's rose speed
Single power only is not obeyed as shown by the Schnees glyphs
Aura Drain is not obeyed as all passive semblances don't use up aura

So what is Qrow's Magic doing that Semblances can't do?

Why would you assume that those are the rules that she's surprised to see broken instead of "no turning into birds"?

That's a very specific rule to have, like with all the shit semblances can do why wouldn't turning into a bird be one of them?

Well, it seems that you recognize that the rules that Semblances may or may not obey do not have to have any relation to the real world—the last three plausible rules that you mention have no real equivalent in the real world (the first one is false, too, but that did take until the 20th century to figure out). So why not "semblances don't turn you into animals" or "don't turn you into birds," even? (Ruby's transformation is implied to not be a "normal' Semblance, either, for that matter).

Anyway, the larger point of Volume 9...not to give too much away if you have not seen it...is that it's all magic in a sense. The division between "Remnant stuff" and "weird Salem/brother god stuff" is in a certain way more artificial than one might think. Though I guess the Grimm kind of make that obvious earlier on, since they are accepted as a natural part of the ecosystem and are...kind of not.

V9 sucks, if there was any change I'd be back after V7, it was killed after the wasp bridge. So really I care too much about a show that I'm never watching again

Also why would animal transformation be too weird?
